# Linux: Delete file as other and as group

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

This question should be asked for a million times, but I colud not find normal answer.

**user** is member of group **adm**

I created as root

```
# touch /tmp/keyboard-backlight.on 
# chmod 666 /tmp/keyboard-backlight.on 
# chgrp adm /tmp/keyboard-backlight.on 
# chgrp adm /tmp/
# echo "text"  > /test.txt
# chmod 0666  /test.txt
```

as user

```
user@host ~ $ rm /tmp/keyboard-backlight.on 
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/keyboard-backlight.on': Operation not permitted
user@host ~ $ rm /test.txt 
rm: cannot remove '/test.txt': Permission denied
```

Why I can't remove this files?

Comment: Please add the output of this commands: `ls -ld /tmp` and also this: `ls -ld /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting and creating files require write permissions for the directory containing the file.

For `/`, it's owned by `root`, and it has no "write" permissions for group or others. So only `root` could delete files there, regardless of the permissions of the file.

```
$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Nov  3 19:21 /
```

Regarding `/tmp`, this folder usually has the sticky bit enabled. See [Linux permissions: SUID, SGID, and sticky bit](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/suid-sgid-sticky-bit):

> The last special permission has been dubbed the "sticky bit." This
> permission does not affect individual files. However, at the directory
> level, it restricts file deletion. Only the **owner** (and **root**) of a file
> can remove the file within that directory. A common example of this is
> the `/tmp` directory:
>
> ```
> [tcarrigan@server article_submissions]$ ls -ld /tmp/ 
> drwxrwxrwt. 15 root root 4096 Sep 22 15:28 /tmp/
> ```
>
> The permission set is noted by the lowercase **t**, where the **x** would
> normally indicate the execute privilege.